# How to stop Watson Assistant from replying to customer when connected to an agent

Tags: facebook, chatbot, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger-bot, watson-assistant

When a customer says they want to connect to an agent, then Watson Assistant gives the prompt that they will be connected. How do we stop Watson Assistant from replying to further inquiries (or messages) automatically?

I have tried making them wait for a response and then not reply, but after 1 message they will reply again and again.

How do I program my Watson Assistant to stop replying?

Comment: What is your chatbot architecture? Do you have an app?

Comment: I strongly advise you to check out https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-zendesk or a similar one with Salesforce